# getReplyQueue method in java rabbitmq client v3.4.3 no longer available?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using Rabbitmq client v3.3.4 & it had getReplyQueue() method which I was using it to consume messages as below:

```
getChannel().basicConsume(getReplyQueue(), true, consumer);
```

Now, I upgraded my rabbitmq server to 3.4.3 & so I decided to upgrade java client library to v3.3.4 but I found that the getReplyQueue() method is no longer present in RabbitMQ Java client library.

How would I get the reply queue in this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `getReplyQueue()` method has nothing to do with the rabbit client library; it looks like it's a method in the class this code is invoked from.

If you are referring to the `RpcClient` class (as mentioned in the deleted answer by Mike Powell); that class now uses [direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html), and thus uses the internal `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` and not a real replyTo queue.